# Get created object with all fields

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I use DBIx::class and postgreSQL.
Imagine table 'Company'. It has fields:

```
id =>  {
  data_type         =>  'integer',
  is_auto_increment =>  1,
},
name => {
  data_type   =>  'text',
},
is_client => {
  data_type     =>  'boolean',
  default_value =>  'true',
},
```

When I create new company passing the company name only, `create` method returns primery key and field I passed: id, name.
How can I get all fields with default values without additional request to DB?
In other words, I want the `create` method to return all fields with defaults to me.

Comment: Where's the code that you've tried?

Comment: Somthing like this: ``` $schema->resultset( 'Company')->create({ name => 'XXX' });

Answer (score 2):

The DBIx::Class::ResultSet create method returns a DBIx::Class::Result object which has all column values filled.
On databases that support it, DBIx::Class uses RETURNING to get back server populated column values.
See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSource#retrieve_on_insert how to use that feature.

Comment: This is a good local solution. But I need all info of any created object, so to add 'retrieve_on_insert' to every field in result schema is not way I wont. I need somthing like ```select *```.

Comment: DBIx::Class already knows all values you've set on create so retrieve_on_insert is only required for database set columns.